# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat works with .war but not .zip

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an application to EC2 with elastic beanstalk and tomcat. In order to try and fix a different problem I had I changed my uploaded file from a .war to a .zip in order to include a .ebextensions folder. However, now I get the following error when trying to enter the website:

[image]

I figured that there might be a problem with the .config file I added, so I tried zipping the .war file alone, however I get the exact same error, so this is ruled out.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: @stdunbar It appears not to add anything to the logs. I looked through the last 100 lines and they were all related to previous issues.

Answer (score 3):

TL/DR: Put 2 .war files in the .zip file instead of 1.

I realize this post is nearly 18 months old. But I experienced exactly the same symptoms, so this seemed as good a place as any to share my discovery.

Premise: deploying a .war file works well, exactly as expected.

Observation: Elastic Beanstalk does this automatically:

```
/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/[contents of .war are placed here]
```

Problem: deploying a .zip file containing this .war file along with valid config files does NOT work well.

Observation: Elastic Beanstalk does this automatically:

```
/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/[my-war.war is placed here]
```

To me this seems like a bug. Perhaps it's intended behavior... but I don't understand it. Placing the .war file in webapps would make sense. Placing the *contents* of the .war in ROOT would make sense. But placing the .war file there directly seems very strange.

Solution: Add a second .war file to the .zip (even if you don't need the second app!).

Observation: Elastic Beanstalk does this automatically:

```
/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/[my-war.war is placed here]
/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/[my-other-war.war is placed here]
```

Now my-war.war deploys normally, and life is good.

Comment: It's definitely a bug! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html `To run multiple applications on the same web server, you can bundle multiple WAR files into a single source bundle. Each application in a multiple WAR source bundle runs at the root path (ROOT.war runs at myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/) or at a path directly beneath it (app2.war runs at myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/app2/), as determined by the name of the WAR. In a single WAR source bundle, the application always runs at the root path.` It specifically says a single WAR bundle runs at /.

Comment: Wow this is an amazing find! Don't forget that your app has to be called `ROOT.war` in order to be deployed on the `/` root path.

Comment: I agree that it is a bug. Thanks for posting your solution!