# How do I create an empty file in Maven assembly?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I see how to create an empty directory in Maven from

[Can I create empty directories while packaging using maven-assembly-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909699/can-i-create-empty-directories-while-packaging-using-maven-assembly-plugin)

But how do you create an empty file in Maven? I need it to work around this Amazon Elastic Beanstalk bug.

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat works with .war but not .zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376178/aws-elastic-beanstalk-tomcat-works-with-war-but-not-zip)

I'm expecting something like

```
<touch>target/empty.war</touch>
```

I tried

```
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>NUL</source>    <!-- Since it's on Windows -->
      <outputDirectory/>
      <destName>empty.war</destName>
```

And

```
  <files>
    <file>
      <source/>
      <outputDirectory/>
      <destName>empty.war</destName>
```

But the latter attempt creates an `empty.war/` *directory* instead of a file! Despite the documentation:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_file

> destName  String  Sets the destination **filename** in the outputDirectory. Default is the same name as the source's file.

Answer (score 0):

I added an empty `empty.war` file to the root of the project and checked it into source control. Then I added the file to the ZIP. This isn't an intuitive way of doing it, but I could find no other.

```
  <files>
    <file>
      <source>empty.war</source>
      <outputDirectory/>
```